Error while compiling a file with GCC, trying to send pulses through the parallel port
I am trying to compile the simple file primeroscomandos.c with GCC:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/io.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BASEPORT 0x378

int main()
{
    if(ioperm(BASEPORT, 3, 1))
    {
        perror(“ioperm”);
        return 1;
    }

    outb(0x01, BASEPORT);
    usleep(100000);

    outb(0x02, BASEPORT);
    usleep(1000000);

    outb(0x00, BASEPORT);
    if(ioperm(BASEPORT, 3, 0))
    {
        perror(“ioperm”);
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

And I receive these errors:
gcc primeroscomandos.c

Output:
primeroscomandos.c: In function ‘main’:
primeroscomandos.c:9:33: error: stray ‘\342’ in program
9 | if(ioperm(BASEPORT,3,1)){perror(<U+201C>ioperm<U+201D>);
  |                                 ^~~~~~~~
primeroscomandos.c:9:40: error: stray ‘\342’ in program
9 | if(ioperm(BASEPORT,3,1)){perror(<U+201C>ioperm<U+201D>);
  |                                               ^~~~~~~~
primeroscomandos.c:9:34: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘perror’ from incompatible pointer type [-        Wincompatible-pointer-types]
9 | if(ioperm(BASEPORT,3,1)){perror(“ioperm”);
  |                                  ^~~~~~
  |                                  |
  |                                  int (*)(long unsigned int,  long unsigned int,  int)

In file included from primeroscomandos.c:1:

/usr/include/stdio.h:804:33: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)(long unsigned int,  long unsigned int,  int)’
  804 | extern void perror (const char *__s);
      |                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
primeroscomandos.c:20:33: error: stray ‘\342’ in program
   20 | if(ioperm(BASEPORT,3,0)){perror(<U+201C>ioperm<U+201D>);
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~
primeroscomandos.c:20:40: error: stray ‘\342’ in program
   20 | if(ioperm(BASEPORT,3,0)){perror(<U+201C>ioperm<U+201D>);
      |                                               ^~~~~~~~
primeroscomandos.c:20:34: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘perror’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   20 | if(ioperm(BASEPORT,3,0)){perror(“ioperm”);
      |                                  ^~~~~~                                  |
      |                                  int (*)(long unsigned int,  long unsigned int,  int)
/usr/include/stdio.h:804:33: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)(long unsigned int,  long unsigned int,  int)’
  804 | extern void perror (const char *__s);
      |                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
*/

They seem to be more or less the same ones.
They will control a step motor through pin 1 = pulses and pin 2 = direction.
I tried to compile it with GCC, but it showed those above problems
in distribution Debian 12 (Bookworm).

You used these weird quoting characters “”, not the normal ".

Thanks a lot ssbssa, now it works properly.

The canonical question is Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc. A more specific one is Stray '\342' in C++ program.

Such errors can positively be identified with the regular expression \x{00A0}|\x{00A6}|\x{00AB}|\x{00AE}|\x{00BB}|\x{00CD}|\x{00E4}|\x{037E}|\x{2003}|\x{2009}|\x{200B}|\x{200C}|\x{2013}|\x{2014}|\x{2018}|\x{2019}|\x{201C}|\x{201D}|\x{2028}|\x{2029}|\x{202A}|\x{202B}|\x{202C}|\x{2060}|\x{21B5}|\x{2212}|\x{2217}|\x{2260}|\x{FEFF}|\x{FF1A}|\x{FFFC}|\x{FFFD}. Or in a different notation (e.g., Visual Studio Code),

cont' - \u00A0|\u00A6|\u00AB|\u00AE|\u00BB|\u00CD|\u00E4|\u037E|\u2003|\u2009|\u200B|\u200C|\u2013|\u2014|\u2018|\u2019|\u201C|\u201D|\u2028|\u2029|\u202A|\u202B|\u202C|\u2060|\u21B5|\u2212|\u2217|\u2260|\uFEFF|\uFF1A|\uFFFC|\uFFFD

cont' - That is for NO-BREAK SPACE, BROKEN BAR, LEFT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK, REGISTERED SIGN, RIGHT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK, LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH ACUTE, LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS, GREEK QUESTION MARK, EM SPACE, THIN SPACE, ZERO WIDTH SPACE, ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER, EN DASH, EM DASH, LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK, RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK, LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK, RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK, LINE SEPARATOR, PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR, LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING, RIGHT-TO-LEFT EMBEDDING,

cont' - POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING, WORD JOINER, DOWNWARDS ARROW WITH CORNER LEFTWARDS, MINUS SIGN, ASTERISK OPERATOR, NOT EQUAL TO, ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE, FULLWIDTH COLON, OBJECT REPLACEMENT CHARACTER, REPLACEMENT CHARACTER, respectively (32)

cont' - Result for this case: Four instances, two “ and two ” (Unicode code point U+201C (LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK) and Unicode code point U+201D (RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK), respectively). In this case, it is heavily hinted at in the error message (once it has been properly formatted).
